# What would an asteroid base look like and how would it operate?

Tags: science-based, space-constructs

For the sake of simplicity, my species is similar to humans but far more advanced. We will also assume that they live in a solar system similar to ours, and that they are advanced enough that they can 'catch' an asteroid and land on it.

These people wish to create a research base which orbits the sun, not the earth. To do so, they are planning to build a base on an asteroid. Assuming this asteroid has a similar orbit to the one shown below, what would this research station look like?

[image: Asteroid orbit]

People would be transported to the base on rockets, and to get back to 'earth' they would eject a pod while the asteroid is travelling towards the planet and drift back home (again, assuming very advanced technology).

The asteroid they have chosen is large (about 900-1000 km diameter) and is made from a combination of carbon compounds, iron and magnesium silicates, nickel, igneous rock, and ice (all in abundance). Its gravitational field strength is around 1/32 of earth's. With an orbit like above, the speeds and temperatures on the surface would be difficult to deal with.

Assuming my race of sentients can land on an asteroid like Ceres, with an orbit similar to Phaethon, what would their asteroid base look like? How would it be operated and what sort of systems would it use? They need to be self-sufficient (produce food) and be able to survive both extremes of the asteroid's orbit. Assume advanced technology, but nothing unrealistic (no time travel, teleportation, or artificial gravity please)

Comment: something to bear in mind, each launch and landing will change the mass of the asteroid, potentially sending it into the sun. Each launch and landing will need to be counterbalanced

Comment: @ChrisJ That is a good thing for people to consider in their answers

Comment: Ceres gravity is 0.028 of Earth's, with similar diameter. How are you planning to have your asteroid have similar size, kinda similar composition, and ten times stronger gravity?

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that even if you time your return transfer window perfectly, you'll have an awful lot of orbital velocity to shed in order to not escape Earth.  Earth does have a nice atmosphere that you can use for aerobraking, but the approach angle required to capture an object moving on such a highly eccentric solar orbit is probably not very healthy for the reentry craft.  Which is to say that you will probably explode (and rather quickly, at that.)  Might need to plan a slingshot maneuver or two to help burn off excess energy, plus pack some fuel and propulsion.

Comment: To rephrase it in a perhaps more visceral image: it's like you're trying to hitch a ride on a train by jumping in front of it and catching it as it runs into you, except the train has the mass of the Earth and it's moving at 30,000 m/s directly toward your face as you move sideways past its direction of motion.

Comment: _drift back home_ Sorry, that is not how space works. As anyone who plays Kerbal Space Program will attest, "slowing down" as as hard as "catching up" to stuff.

Comment: Yes, but can't you just drift close to the planet and enter a high orbit? From there you can simply use a skyhook or a small amount of fuel to slow down and fall into the atmosphere. Landing is easy, you just use some parachutes and flotation devices.

Comment: @AricFowler Nope. It's harder.

Comment: Assuming advanced technology beyond our current understanding, what then?

Comment: @AricFowler You are so mistaken :( "small amount of fuel"? You need the same amount of fuel to enter orbit as you need to leave it. And not tearing your skyhook station apart with such a high velocity difference. Kerbal Space Program suggested by Euphoric is really great to get this kind of insight and intuition.

Comment: I realise that it is very difficult to acheive, but the operative points are that this is _worldbuilding_ where we talk about fictional worlds. My race is extremely advanced, so maybe they have discovered an energy source which is light and powerful? It doesnt matter how they get into and out of orbit, as long as the science sounds plausible enough to possibly happen in the distant future.

Comment: @AricFowler, I think the main point myself and others were making is that the orbit you've pictured doesn't actually make it easier to return to Earth; in fact, that's probably one of the most difficult (high-energy requirement) return paths, since you're literally traveling orthogonal to the direction you need to be going if you want to catch up with earth.  Your lowest energy intercept would probably be to start from the highest point of asteroid orbit and accelerate (so that your periapsis intersects Earth), then decelerate upon arrival for orbital capture and subsequent reentry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some consideration has to be made abut the composition of the asteroid. If it is a solid mass, then you will essentially be tunnelling into it like the NORAD bunker in Cheyenne Mountain. However, current theory suggests that asteroids are loose piles of rubble with lots of spaces in between, so the interior of the asteroid is almost like a sponge. A very large asteroid such as you describe could have a very interesting composition. Some of the data from Ceres seems to suggest there is a lot of water trapped inside.

Regardless of the composition, once you have burrowed inside, you will have very little gravity. Creatures evolved on a planet would prefer some simulation of gravity, both for health and comfort, and because it makes working easier (tools don't float away, for example). So the space inside should be cleared enough to build a rotating space station that provides a gravitational simulation.

This concept can be expanded to create what is known as a [Gravity Balloon](http://www.scifiideas.com/science-2/colonizing-asteroid-cores/). The concept is explained in detail at the link, but the explanation is simple. A large enough space is found or excavated, lined with an airtight membrane and filled with air. Tension cables are strung along the interior, and rotating structures strung along like beads to provide the living space where a simulation of gravity is created.

[image]

*The rotating structure everyone lives in*

This illustration would be for a very ambitious colony, an external mirror transfers sunlight into the interior and the small black dots are rotating structures 500m in length to give you an idea of scale:

[image]

Most of the other details of day to day operations can be gleaned from sites like [Atomic Rockets](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/index.php), and many of the other posters have mentioned many of the factors needed to operate in space.

Comment: Even though i said "no artificial gravity", this idea seems plausible. Also i like the way the chamber is cone shaped to allow for a gravity gradient as you walk along it.

Comment: As regards to zero gravity however, they seem to do ok on the ISS... You could possibly have an 'ant's nest' design dug into the asteroid... The minimal gravity would let people float down the tunnels, and you could make it airtight to contain an atmosphere inside it.

Comment: @AricFowler it depends on how long your crew will be there, following on from the tours on the ISS there is a weakening of muscles as they have so little to do. Also gravity is nice to have so you can do things like use the toilet normally and not worry about your tears forming big watery balloons on your eyes

Comment: @ChrisJ Considering that the orbit of such an asteroid can take several years, i think it would be wise to have gravity then. Otherwise you're going to be stuck in zero gravity for a looong time, slowly wasting away.....

Answer (score 31):

## Underground base

The base will need to be underground to provide protection from radiation. Even just being in Earth orbit is a [major radiation hazard when the solar wind is heavy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_threat_from_cosmic_rays) The reason we do not fry here on the ground is because the Earth's magnetic field and its atmosphere protect us.

[image]

*These pretty lights are where the atmosphere blocks particles that would otherwise kill you through severe radiation poisoning*

Your asteroid has no atmosphere and no magnetic field worth speaking of, and it goes into the very "stormy" regions of the solar system, right next to the Sun. By the look of that diagram, it even passes close enough to touch [the corona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona).

**This means the radiation hazard is extreme. If this base is sweeping that close to the Sun, they will need very heavy radiation shields.**

Best way to do that would be to 1) bore down into the asteroid, since stone and metal-rich minerals protect very well, and 2) place the water tanks between themselves and the Sun. [Water is an excellent radiation shield](https://what-if.xkcd.com/29/).

[image]

*The major danger of taking a swim in a nuclear fuel pool is that the guards will be very cross with you for contaminating the ultra-pure water in the pool, you filthy thing you*

**So the main distinguishing feature of your base is that it needs to be underground.**

All work sites related to this base will need to be underground as well, or be shielded, or have radiation hardened bunkers nearby where people can go when things get "hot".

This was a concern on the [Apollo missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_program) when — on the later, long duration [J-type missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apollo_mission_types) — the astronauts went for long treks on the [Lunar Rover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Roving_Vehicle). NASA was very nervously watching the Sun for activity, because if the Sun had flared, Mission Control would have needed to recall the astronauts and have them take shelter in the [Lunar Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module) to protect them from the resulting radiation.

With this I would expect the base to have one or several dedicated [tunnel boring machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_boring_machine) in operation.

## Energy

Fusion reactors. Someone else suggested solar panels but I digress on that. Solar panels are extremely heavy compared to the power they give, and when you travel in space, you want to keep things as light as possible compared to the amount of "usefulness" they provide. If your heroes are "far more advanced" than us, then just assume they have mastered fusion instead. Energy is probably a non-issue.

[image]

*Bring your [handy fusion reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polywell), and energy will not be an issue. Plus you have a very sci-fi looking element of your futuristic base. ([Source](http://www.emc2fusion.org/))*

## Water, air

<s>This will need to be brought, or — if they bring an extra fusion reactor — they can break apart materials on the asteroid to form these on site. Hydrogen is everywhere in the universe, and so is Oxygen. You just need **energy** to break apart minerals and molecules to form the right stuff.</s>

**After the edit to the question:** If there is ice on the asteroid, this is a non-issue. Use the fusion reactors to melt and purify the ice for water; use electrolysis to make Oxygen from the water.

Purification and re-circulation of waste water / waste air will probably be necessary.

## Food

Expect that to need to be stockpiled. Unless of course — like air and water — you expect to be able to manufacture that on site. But unless your heroes have Star Trek type replicators it will probably be quite boring food... rather simple nutritional pastes and fluids, simple sugars.

Do note that this makes for a nice plot element when the transport from Earth comes with the good stuff... steak, juice, drinks. Also note that during the perihelion (passage closest to the Sun), no transports can come... the radiation is too heavy. And there is probably very little work to do during perihelion since they have to huddle in the radiation proofed areas of the base, sucking on their protein pastes and mineral-supplements.

Comment: +1 for scientific precision and explainations about solar panels. Excellent answer there.

Comment: what about growing plants using water and air? you can get carbon and minerals from the asteroid itself... maybe grow the plants hydroponically?

Comment: @AricFowler Well I suppose that is possible. It would certainly add some welcome additions to the food provisions. I suppose it is a matter of how much effort your intrepid adventurers wish to spend on this operation. Or more precisely: how much their sponsors wish to spend.

Comment: @AricFowler Do note though: **nitrogen** is important here. Plants need that. Where are you getting the nitrogen?

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors point taken.

Comment: Technicality in your excellent answer: orbiting the sun it would be perihelion, not perigee.  The base word for any orbit is periapsis, but the suffix is changed based on what body you are orbiting - gee for Earth, helion for the sun, and others for other bodies.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsis

Comment: @Cody Point taken. :)

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors its a really minor detail, but its bugged me whenever someone uses it wrong ever since I started playing Kerbal Space Program

Comment: @Cody Well I have not made it into heliocentric orbit in KSP... only gone around Kerbin so far. So that is why I used the wrong term. ;)

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors wait till you make it out to Jool, its fun playing gravity assists with the 3 inner moons

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors: There's nitrogen in your piss. And of course you could stockpile some fertilizer.

Comment: @celtschk True enough, and since — presumably — we are dealing with closed systems that could work. I just don't know how effectively Nitrogen recycling can be performed.

Comment: @PEMapModder What?! You use the **energy** from the reactor to purify the water, you don't run the water **into** the reactor, that would be folly! :)

Answer (score 3):

(First answer ever here, I'm not sure to be specific enough)

Survival will be hard. Asteroids having no atmosphere, your base should be able to resist very high temperatures, nothing stopping the energy from the sun they orbit around to get directly to your base. You would also need some heavy energy-absorption systems and ventilation if you do not want your base to hold some human barbecue. Those conditions are necessary only if you want an orbit similar to Phaethon, which passes [very close to the sun](http://www.thelivingmoon.com/43ancients/04images/Asteroids/Phaethon_orbit.jpg) at some point.

Assuming very advanced technology, they could build some kind of railway building very quickly, in order to dodge going close to the sun. It would automatically adapt to get to the opposite face when it goes near the sun, and facing the sun when it is far enough. Detection systems like antennas or anything could do this positionning decision trick.

About the look of your building ... It is all up to you. The only restriction I would give you is to make it as flat as possible. The composition of your asteroid makes me feel like a huge building will have a rough time getting solid foundations, and the speeds there will be tremendous for it to bear. A maximum of one floor, maybe ? I don't know, but make it kind of flat. In my vision, it would greatly ressemble [houses from Dragon Ball Z ?](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/9/95/900.png/revision/latest?cb=20110219010425) This way, you'll divide the weight of your building throughout the asteroid's surface, and won't have to think about very deep structures.

For the deployment, you have advanced technology. Automatic building deployment could be a thing, as [it already exists](http://www.rapidbuiltshelters.com/) in some extend. You could improve it to make automatic foundation digging (careful, not too deep) and room-repartition deployment. It lands, it deploys, humans can come and go.

**EDIT**

Energy is not a problem, you have the Sun. Solar panels will absorb the energy for you and feed the electrical system. So you have power to keep your food nice and cold, until it is consumed.

I doubt any prey for humans would live there naturally. You would have to transport it from your "main planet". I think lyophilized food will allow you to transport a lot of food, so you can limit your transport cost. Your base should plan some kind of landing field, so you can get both humans and supply to come (and go) to your base.

If they want to go back to base, there are numerous solutions. A small number of humans may be able to go for it through escape pods, be it classical propulsion or heavy-calculated launch through space to Earth. If you want to leave entirely, the building would have, **of course**, some "zipping" functionnality (as you deployed them). Call the Earth, tell them you are all planning to leave. Send the equipment first, then most of scientists, then a space ship could come and take back the building and the few engineers staying.

Comment: Food is also a concern. How will the base run? Where will they get food and how will they generate electricity? What sort of system would they use to launch back towards 'earth'?

Comment: I will try to elaborate. You asked for that the base will "look like" :p.

Comment: Yeah i realised... I didn't mean to say that haha

Comment: Remember that nothing is absolute here. It is only my own view of what an asteroid base would look like, given your conditions. You can still twist the ideas around if you want to :p

Comment: @Yassine Badache i fully understand; I edited my question to make it clearer what i am looking for to make it clearer.

Comment: What about farming on the asteroid? There is carbon compounds so you could probably take some nutrients to make soil.

Comment: "Energy is not a problem, you have the Sun". Heh... there is a very good reason that large space probes that go to Mars and beyond to not rely on solar panels, but on nuclear power: there is not enough Sun out there to provide. The inverse square law is a right [female dog] in this regard. So no, that statement is not true. If these people expect to do any kind of serious work, especially at the apogee, they need something that outputs more energy than that, especially considering how **heavy** solar panels are in comparison to what power they give.

Comment: Asteroids usually rotate too fast for a moving building to be useful as a protection from the sun. See Michael's answer for an alternative. Other than that, nice answer, +1.

Comment: I'm accepting every constructive criticism. Seriously, you guys here are way more kind that on StackOverflow. Thanks @MichaelKarnerfors for the feedback, did not think about being sufficiently far away to not be able to "farm sun".

Comment: @YassineBadache All of the 'easy' and 'simple' questions have been answered on stack overflow, so unless you have a reeeally complicated question that noone can answer, you will likely get downvoted and labelled as duplicate. this is why i use stack overflow for research and little else. Asking questions is pointless :/

Answer (score 1):

Wait wait wait... While resources and stuff has been addressed already (I'm voting for fusion reactor btw.... I wonder if you can grab/soak/inhale new fusion material while drifting through suns corona...) something just spoke of in a comment @Dan Bryant and @Euphoric is pretty vital to the whole story.

### Rendezvous with the asteroid

so... I do not know what kind of future advanced technology your civilization does own, but if they cannot offer vessel that has a deltaV of... huh...

- remove earth-velocicy (30km/s)
- correct ascending node and perihelion (about 5km/s?)
- rendezvous burning (5km/s?)
- and back: remove orbital speed of base-asteroid at earth' semi-major-axis (hm... 5km/s?)
- gain earth orbit velocity (30km/s)
- break to decent back to earth (7km/s, while here much aerobraking can be done)

means about 80km/s deltaV... ehm, deltaV is the total change of speed of a spcecraft provided by its engines (and fuel niveau). Okay, these are estimates beyond any calculation, so maybe the real number is even bigger.

Thats pretty insane. The only useful alternative would be a Hohnmann-Transfer to the asteroids aphelion and than a braking burn, which would be quite fuel efficient. Still, thats beyond today capabilities, and even if you could do this, you only have a narrow timeframe every year when the transfer would be most efficient (I would guess when the earth is at the suns other side).

So as long as your spacecraft arn't capable of these stunts, please go for a more relaxed asteroid.

### Cooling

Okay... half the distance of Mercury? Did you bring some insane cooling radiators with you? Don't think a lump of rock will keep you cool enough when coming this close to sun. While you will have the energy to fuel this, you need some real batshit engineered apparatus to get rid of excess heat.

Cooling Doesn't sound so fancy, but without an atmosphere to carry away heat, all you have is blackbody-radiation, which need huge surfaces to work properly. Surfaces that shold not point to the bright, warm thingy that will cover up half of the visible sky. So no asteroid rotation or the cooling apparatus needs to be even more interesting.

### Station keeping

Last but not least - you are passing through suns most outer part of atmosphere...  A T M O S P H E R E. every time you are at the closest point, you will loose some momentum due to friction. When not accelerating the whole asteroid one day in future even the best heat-radiators won't keep you cool any more.

So... yeah, there are plenty of cute asteroids out there which don't require such an effort to went to. if there isn't any really fine stuff located at that heap of stone and metal, leave it be alone.

### Plane Shift

That's the second edit about something I forgot in the beginning: That astroid needs to be at a pretty inclined plane compared to these of the other planets; because he is passing at least four other celestial bodys during his orbit (which are all in the (way) > 10e22kg mass range) all of them would be able to throw him into the sun or make him a runaway when he comes inside their sphere of influence. Or just plain crash (which is highly unlikely but still an valid option).

What does this mean? Not only you need to arrange with that eccentric orbit, you need to adjust to a probably insane inclined plane, which is even less of a pleasure to compute.

---

EDiT: I have to admit, the latest comments made me think... advanced technology *may* be able to convert even the heat gained by the close distance to sun into thrust... just funnel this to a point where some kind of expanding propellant is stored. Hell, you could get thrust by applying microwave laser to your most retrograde part of that rock; the surface melting and subliming away will provide forward momentum (but how much... and one day our asteroid will be... used). 
The skyhook... wiki says you get about 3.5km/s in theory. Still missing 60km/s. This comes down to pure math. Which I'm not good at. If you employ a mass-driver for spaceships you might be off better.

If your spaceship can use any form of an ion drive (or something similar) than reaction mass (and ship mass difference between dry and wet) would be a negligible problem, but you need aeons to apply the thrust.

I'm still for an asteroid in a much nicer orbit ;)

Comment: Using [thermal energy storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_energy_storage) could they perhaps store heat from the sun for heating when in the outer reaches of the solar system, and then reduce their temperature by absorbing heat again while close to the sun? Apparently, [seasonal thermal energy storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonal_thermal_energy_storage) is the storage of heat or cold for periods of up to several months. Could this work?

Comment: Perhaps a [skyhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_(structure)) or two could solve the acceleration/deceleration... Remember that we are assuming advanced technology beyond our current understanding!

Comment: The Hohmann transfer window is when departing the apoapsis of the asteroid's orbit with the right velocity to set the new solar orbit periapsis to coincide with Earth would also cause the return vehicle to get to that point at the same time as Earth.  There will be a particular phase angle between the Earth and the asteroid orbits where this transfer is possible.  In other words, you don't throw the ship at the Earth, you throw the ship at where the Earth will be, but so it also coincides with roughly the direction it's moving at the time.  You try to best match position _and_ velocity.

Comment: @DanBryant, if you can afford inefficient thrusting because of an abundance of deltaV, they might be able to "jump off" the asteroid and waste propellant as long as necessary until they (first) got rid of the asteroids inherited orbital velocity and (second) got earth velocity and (third) changed their plane to that of earth... when reading this, that sounds ridiculous. Shifting between these two bodys in an efficient way would include some pretty gravity-assist-dancing and years of flight-time, wouldn't it?

Comment: Gravity assists can help make it more efficient, but a Hohmann transfer will still be pretty efficient if you can tolerate a year or so of flight time, as well as waiting a few years between transfer windows.  If you have extra delta-V, you can widen the transfer window and get their sooner by deliberately intersecting Earth's orbit at less favorable approach angles, which also means extra delta-V required to enter orbit.  This will still be vastly more efficient than the sideways approach, which, as you stated, requires achieving almost the entire orbital velocity of Earth from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with the simple idea, that there wouldn't be a base in an asteroid at all unless it served another purpose than just 'research'.

That purpose could be anything from surveillance, where the asteroid might be span to produce 'gravity', to a military installation with a mass driver, to a factory that produced high tensile strength  cable and lowers it onto planets for a relatively mobile space elevator / counterweight in one. whereby the base would stay in a stable geostationary orbit for a time.

Much of the equipment on board would depend on the purpose of this asteroid base. I mean, what does an asteroid base in a fairly erratic orbit provide that the ISS cannot do in the real world?

I don't see any logical reason why any 'intelligent' species would just build a base in an asteroid with such an orbit. Unless the goal is to obfuscate their goals they'd capture it and put it into a more stable orbit, probably mine it for raw resources.

Food's easy: multi-level robotic greenhouses.

Water is easy, they already have ice.

Radiation protection comes from the thickness of the rock and some extra gold foil around the viewing areas.

For power, I'd assume that this species would already have solar panels in orbit, and can laser the energy into the base. No weather, no day night cycle, affordable and infinite. Heck, maybe the asteroid base is a maintenance station for the species' new dyson swarm.

Gravity is trickier, either spinning it or constantly accelerating it, either one provides problems that are fairly intuitive.

Controlling the asteroid shouldn't be too hard, solar sails are surprisingly effective (both cost and usability), and can even be designed to allow for tacking and beating toward the sun.

Keeping that orbit would only help if the goal is to:

Survey something inconspicuously.

Attack something unexpectedly.

Maybe the base is nothing but a giant flywheel, and your species is moving it into a more stable orbit in order to:

Turn this base into a counterweight for a space elevator.

Mining for rare metals

space-based construction of solar panels

other goals, like tourism, are equally applicable to either one, but a more steady orbit would help people arrive and leave.

Comment: Hi, welcome to worldbuilding! This question refers to an advanced race which is on the verge of travelling out of their solar system. Using an asteroid, the research base is able to travel from close to the sun all the way into the outer reaches of the solar system. This lets them study each planet and moon in close detail, and can also act as a slingshot to send probes into deep space.